# use CMAKE to copy compile_commands.json to project root

Tags: cmake

This is the content I have in my `CMakeLists.txt` file that is located in my project root:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(cmake_wrapper)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
add_custom_target(
    copy-compile-commands ALL
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/compile_commands.json
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
    )

# I am using conan & everything works fine, so you may ignore 2 lines below
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup() 

# add submodule
add_subdirectory(src)
```

Then I run `cmake ..` in my `build` folder, and I got the `compile_commands.json` generated in build folder but I didn't see the file been copied into my project root.

UPDATE:
So seems I need to run build/make to trigger this step.
Is there a way to copy the file before run `make` but right after the `compile_commands.json` been generated?

Comment: **Bigger picture:** it's not at all clear why this is necessary. It smells like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: For setups where you have a linter that needs to know the context for compiling, you need access to this file.  By default, they often just search up the path to find it, but non-in-source-builds will be in a separate branch off that path, so won't be found.  Copying it (or symlinking) into the source path makes it easy to find the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copying, create a symlink. At configure stage.

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/compile_commands.json
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/compile_commands.json
)
```

Comment: It does work on windows - it does not work on filesystems that do not support links. Like on FAT.

Answer (score 1):

> So seems I need to run build/make to trigger this step. Is there a way to copy the file before run make but right after the compile_commands.json been generated?

**No.** CMake generates the `compile_commands.json` during the generation step which happens immediately *after* your CMake code runs (configure step) and before the generated build system runs (build step).

CMake has no features to execute arbitrary CMake code during generation.